# Insertar imagenes con React js

Tags: reactjs, img

Estoy empezando a trabajar con React pero tengo problemas al insertar imagenes, a través del tag img dentro del atributo src le paso la dirección de la imagen pero me muestra como si no encontrara la imagen.

**index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/index.css';

function Options(){
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <label htmlFor="usr"><b>Nombre de Usuario o email</b></label>
            <input type="text" id="usr" required/>

            <label htmlFor="pass"><b>Contraseña</b></label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" required/>
        </div>
    );
}

function UserImage(props){
    return(
        <div className="container-img">

            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
        </div>

    );
}


class Login extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            pass: null,
            usr: null
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(){

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="imgbg"></div>
                <form action="" metod="post">
                    <UserImage/>
                    <Options/>
                    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Login/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Aca dejo el sistema de archivos que estoy usando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puede observarse en la carpeta src tengo index.js en cual se encuentra la etiqueta img src="img/logo.png" la cual referencia a la imagen logo, dentro del sistema de archivos puede observarse que efectivamente si se encuentra la imagen almacenada

Answer (score 3):

Si creaste tu aplicacion con `create-react-app` entonces la carpeta `public` es publica y accesible, podrias mover tu carpeta de imagenes ahi y accederlas asi

```
<img src="/img/logo.png" />
```

Otra opcion seria importar las imagenes en tu componente, por ejemplo:

```
import Logo from './logo.png';

const Component = () => (
   <img src={Logo} alt="logo" />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excelente respuesta, yo tenía el mismo problema y evidentemente, al insertar mi imagen en la carpeta "images" dentro del folder "public" habiendo creado mi aplicación en "create react app" pude acceder a mi imagen al renderizarla en mi componente por medio del atributo "src", thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/406971)